# Use loading image before the content success loading in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used JSON to retrieve data from my controller and print it on my view using jquery. The content is display when users click on the menu link. Before the content load, user have to wait a few second.

So in this period, I want to display the loading image in my view, and when the content is display success, the loading image hide.

This is the html that I put the loading image :

```
<div id="loading" style="position:relative; text-align:center;">  
   <img src="/Content/Images/loading.gif" alt="Processing" />
</div>
```

This is the sample function of jquery :

```
function ViewProduct() {
  $('#loading').hide();
  $("#content ul#navmenu-v").empty();
  $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
     $.each(data, function (index, dataOption) {
     var new_li = $("<li class='level1' id='select_list'><a href='javascript:void(0);' id='" + dataOption.ID + "' class ='selectedcategory'>" + dataOption.Name + "</a>");
        mainMenu.append(new_li);
        $('a#' + dataOption.ID).click(function () {
            //display the loading image
            $.getJSON("ProductListing/Index", data, function (product) {
                //append the content in the body of web page
            });
        });
    });
});
```

}

This is where I called the function :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   ViewProduct();
});
```

Question : I want to hide the loading image after click. Anyone can tell me about this? Thanks so much.

Comment: not sure what you want... your loading image already hidden by this `$('#loading').hide();`

Comment: Hide in here, just hide the loading image while the document is ready, but while I click on the link, the loading image is display.

Comment: `$("blahblah").click(function () { $('#loading').show(); });`

Comment: Yes, but after show in this block, I don't know how to hide it.

Comment: if is ajax content being loaded, place `hide()` in ajax success callback.

Comment: Thanks. Excuse me, in my code, have no ajax success call back. Could you tell me, where should I put the ajax success callback in my jquery block?

Comment: You haven't shown the code used in menu loading, so not sure what method you are using. Look at JQuery API  for mehtod used http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: Please have a look at my function, I edited it ready. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.getJSON(url, [, data], [, callback])` is shorthand for

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback
});
```

The [jQuery.ajax specification](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) shows that we can specify a callback that will fire whether or not the AJAX request succeeds. We will use it to hide the loading icon after the request:

```
function ViewProduct() {
    $('#loading').hide();
    $("#content ul#navmenu-v").empty();

    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, dataOption) {
        var new_li = $("<li class='level1' id='select_list'><a href='javascript:void(0);' id='" + dataOption.ID + "' class ='selectedcategory'>" + dataOption.Name + "</a>");
        mainMenu.append(new_li);
        $('a#' + dataOption.ID).click(function () {

            //display the loading image
            $('#loading').show();

            $.ajax({
                'type': 'GET',
                'url': 'ProductListing/Index',
                'data': data,
                'dataType': 'json',
                'success': function (product) {
                    //append the content in the body of web page
                },
                'complete': function () {
                    $('#loading').hide();
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, but when I did this, It has 1 error in my error consol `Invalid Label` near `$.ajax(function () { 'type': 'GET', ... `. Could you give me some solution please?